# Resolving multiple map dependencies in javascript using gulp task or similar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I have a js folder in which there are angular files and other third party js files, but unfortunately there are few map files.So, I want to write a gulp task or similar which can resolve all the map file in a js folder. For example :

1. js folder

   - angular.js
   - angular-message.js
   - and some third party

Comment: have you tried creating a gulp file? Can you post anything you have tried?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt no I don't have much idea of gulp. So, if you can help?